# Combining two lists into a sentences(python)

Tags: python, string

I have two lists in a list:

```
t = [['this','is','a','sentence'],['Hello','I','am','Daniel']]
```

I want to combine them in order to get two sentences:

```
'this is a sentence. Hello I am Daniel.'
```

I quickly came up with the following solution:

```
text = ''
for sent in t:
  text = text + ' '.join(sent) + '. '
```

But maybe there is more readable(better styled) solution for this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can shorten it to a single list comprehension, with another "." at the end:

```py
text = '. '.join(' '.join(sent) for sent in t) + '.'
```

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA thanks! always important to make sure output is an exact match :D

Comment: Note that actually building the intermediate list: `'. '.join([' '.join(sent) for sent in t])` is a bit faster (10 to 20%). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/550094) that explains why.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `list comprehensions`:

```
In [584]: ''.join([' '+ ' '.join(sent) + '. ' for sent in t])                                                                                                                                               
Out[584]: ' this is a sentence.  Hello I am Daniel. '
```